# Change Windows time using SetLocalTime() without rebooting

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clock

We are setting up an embedded Windows system which needs to have a function to change the system date and time. Our system does not shut down normally just like a normal PC, instead, the user will cut the power directly.

The problem comes when we tried to use the Win API function like SetLocalTime() (with admin rights), the API succeeded when the function just executed, but when the user restarts the machine (i.e. cut the power and turning it on again), the date setting is reverted back to the previous date setting. Looks like the OS cache the setting which requires a normal restart to store the setting to disk.

Does anyone know how to "flush the data cache" immediately without restarting the OS?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [SetSystemTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtime) ?

Comment: Your PC doesn't have a RTC?

Comment: We have tried SetSystemTime() but still have the same issue.

Comment: Our PC have a RTC. We have tried to re-produce this issue with a normal Windows 10 OS too. In normal Win 10 OS, choosing "Adjust Date/Time" (with "Set time automatically" and "Set time zone automatically" both off already), then change the date and cut off the PC power. Then switching it on again and the date is reset back to previous date...

Comment: If you go into BIOS and change the date or time, does that work? Is the CMOS battery (which powers the RTC) okay?

Comment: Yes, going into the BIOS can change. CMOS battery is ok. We tried with normal PC and the problem seems to be the OS cache the setting until the PC shut down/restart normally. But our case need hard shutdown (i.e. cut off power directly) which the OS does not "flush the cached" date settings...

Comment: Wait a minute... I recognize this now... Yes that's correct. Windows doesn't set the RTC until it shuts down. I remember that now. I don't remember the source though. It should be possible to find sources quite easily though. You need to write directly to the RTC (which I don't know how to do) besides setting the time in the running Windows environment.

Comment: "the user will cut the power directly". Fix the real problem. PC's aren't designed to be shut down like that. In fact, hardware design explicitly prevents this. Older PC's had a hard power switch, but modern PC's have a power button which performs a controlled shut down.

Comment: This is deep into undocumented behavior, unfortunately. From what I can tell by looking at the disassembled code in Windows 10 and the reverse-engineered routines (circa NT 5) in ReactOS, if the system isn't in CMOS mode (i.e. `nt!ExpSystemIsInCmosMode`), then `NtSetSystemTime` should immediately call the HAL function `HalSetRealTimeClock` to update the CMOS clock with local time (or possibly UTC if `nt!ExpRealTimeIsUniversal` is set). The system starts up in CMOS mode but the first time `nt!ExpRefreshTimeZoneInformation` is called it should set `ExpSystemIsInCmosMode` to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the ExpSystemIsInCmosMode information. Do you know is there a way to change it back to true? Thank you.

Comment: From what I can tell in looking at the internal function `nt!ExpSetSystemTime`, a false value should make it update the CMOS RTC with the new local time. Can you enable local kernel debugging and check `dd nt!ExpSystemIsInCmosMode l1` in WinDbg? Also check `dd nt!ExpRealTimeIsUniversal l1`.

Comment: Sorry to the late reply. executing those commands have the following result:

lkd> dd nt!ExpSystemIsInCmosMode l1
fffff803`06506f60  00000000
lkd> dd nt!ExpRealTimeIsUniversal l1
fffff803`06553708  00000000

which seems like the variables are false, but the clock time still don't write the changes to disk...

Answer (score 1):

There are two workaround you can check to see if it helps:

1. After change Windows time you explicitly execute a reboot to enable your changes to be written to disk before the user cut the power directly. You can use the following API to reboot the system:

   `ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT | EWX_FORCE,
           SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
           SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
           SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED)`

   Ref: "[How to Shut Down the System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shutdown/how-to-shut-down-the-system)"
2. [Caching can be turned off for a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-caching) is opened by passing FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING as a value for the dwFlagsAndAttributes parameter of [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createfilea). When caching is disabled, all read and write operations directly access the physical disk. So you can store the time on a such file and read it when the system reboot and set it again([Starting an Scheduled task on System Boot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/starting-an-executable-on-system-boot)).